# Exclude css from parent application(angular) from applying into child(react) in single-spa-application

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, webpack, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have made a single-spa application where I am using angular as a parent project and put react bundle into it. Now the problem coming is that react is picking up the CSS of the angular project. I have excluded that particular CSS in webpack.config file of react project. But that isn't working in the way I wanted. S what should be done?

Answer (score -1):

Nothing about single-spa changes the nature of how CSS works. It is the exact same as you would do without single-spa, namely, using techniques like CSS Modules, or scoped/prefixed styles. Using component styles is the most common approach in angular for this: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles